# Unittest's subTest doesn't work with Pytest, or am I crazy?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, python-unittest

As I understand, pytest should provide parameter information with`unittest.TestCase.subtest()` if a test fails. So here is something that resembles my code:

```py
class TestStuff(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_foo(self):
        for i in range(0, 100):
            with self.subTest(msg = "seed", i = i):
                np.random.seed(i)
                n = np.random.randint(0, 30)
                self.assertGreaterEqual(28, n)
```

This ofcourse fails, and prints out the following:

```
================================================================================================== test session starts ===================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-5.0.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0
rootdir: /Users/foopackage
plugins: openfiles-0.3.2, arraydiff-0.3, doctestplus-0.3.0, remotedata-0.3.1
collected 7 items                                                                                                                                                                                                        

foo.py ......F                                                                                                                                                                                               [100%]

======================================================================================================== FAILURES ========================================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________________________ TestStuff.test_foo _________________________________________________________________________________________________

self = <foo.test_foo.TestStuff testMethod=test_foo>

    def test_foo(self):
        for i in range(0, 100):
            with self.subTest(msg = "seed", i = i):
                np.random.seed(i)
                n = np.random.randint(0, 30)
>               self.assertGreaterEqual(28, n)
E               AssertionError: 28 not greater than or equal to 29

foo.py:135: AssertionError
=========================================================================================== 1 failed, 6 passed in 1.91 seconds ===========================================================================================
```

As you can see, there are no message about which seed (value of i) failed the test. I have read everywhere that Pytest is compatible with unittest, so I cant seem to see the problem here. Can someone explain this? Thx

Comment: Why using subtests when you have [test parametrization](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#parametrize-basics) with `pytest`? `@pytest.mark.parametrize('i', range(100)) det test_foo(i): ...`

Comment: You are not crazy. I'm having trouble finding authoritative confirmation that this is true, but empirically, they don't really work well for me. They *do* execute all the variations, which is the most important bit, but they don't do any of the other functionality of subTests, such as executing all variations even if one fails. It's as though the 'self.subTest' was a no-op context manager.

Answer (score 4):

the pytest-subtest plugin is needed to add that feature

Answer (score 0):

For people coming in like me, check if you are using Nosetests instead. I've added it to our project at some point to get test coverage out and several months later we noticed that `subTest` don't execute separately (when stuff broke, as usual), and were trying to figure out why all of the sudden subTests are executing inline with main tests.

Other things to look that are not directly related but might help:

1. If you are using PyCharm, pay attention to how your tests are running. It might explicitly run them with nosetest, pytest or unittest instead of Django manage.py RunTests.
2. In PyCharm you (or someone else) can switch off Django testcase runner, you (see PyCharm > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Django > Do not use Django test runner)
3. In PyCharm you can also select a default testcase runner forcibly (for new configs). See PyCharm > Settings > Tools >Python Integrated Tools > Testing (section) > Default test runner
4. In `settings.py` of your Django app you can also specify a test runner. Mine was, again, nosetest, which doesn't properly work as far as PyCharm & Django goes (for me).
5. Make sure your test runner IS compatible with subTests. As far as I know pytest and unittest are fine. Everything else your mileage may vary
6. Make sure you are inheriting from a correct TestCase. `django.test.TestCase` is `unittest.TestCase` and supports subTest since v3.4 (of unittest)

Answer (score 0):

Simply installing pytest-subtest worked for me:
`pip install pytest-subtest`

Comment: use `pip install pytest-subtests`, there is a typo at package name.